# How To stop Background service when i close app i want to stop background music

Tags: android, android-service

I have background service in my android app,i start service from Splash_activity `onCreate()` method and it is work correctly.But how can i stop service when user press home_activity backpress.Because currently when user press home button then  application close but background music continuously play. i can't stop background music. Below is my code for start service -

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundServi.class);
startService(svc);
```

I want to stop background music in home_activity back press button because i start service in splash activity and when user back multiple(as per user needs) time  then it's come in home activity and then close application. i m already try `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onBackpress()` and stackoverflow all another solution and also read service full process for close services but i can't able to fix issue pls helm me i am new in android.

Also i want to settings on/off background music option what should i do for that...? and how it's work.

Comment: Try the code and tell, if worked or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `home_activity` use:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(home_activity.this,BackgroundSoundService.class));      
}
```

Comment: Error:(124, 15) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(Activity_Latest,Class<BackgroundSoundService>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Activity_Latest cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Activity_Latest cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: add your proper classname.this

Comment: public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  stopService(new Intent(Activity_Latest.this,BackgroundSoundService.class));
 }    BackgroundSoundService is proper class name & Activity_Latest Service is my home activity

Comment: are u using this as a life cycle right, not inside anywhere like oncreate ?

Comment: Yes. i am using outside oncreate()

Comment: @pinalzala, it has to work, because it is working for me

Comment: i m to much confused to implement onPause() in   Activity_Latest because  Activity_Latest extends by Fragment then method public View onCreateView() . it's don't allow me to use stopService() then how to implement onPause()

Comment: than use `getActivity()`

Comment: application unfortunately stop when call  Activity_Latest but background music play still fetch same issue...

Comment: No error code display in logcat and unfortunately issue fix but only two home and splash activity background music play when cal any other activity background music stop